# How to extract data in between a tag in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How do i extract the data  after the class that is "HELP FILE". Here this text HELP FILE is a link when clicked on it leads me to another form.
Can anyone of you please suggest me how to proceed with it. I am a newbie to Selenium, i am struck up over here. I tried by extracting xpath but it gives me the path of my home page
I am using selenium webdriver  and eclipse ide. My project supports only IE.

```
<TD align="left" width="185px" NOWRAP valign="top">
    <a class="wlcmhding"><IMG  SRC="../../images/image1.jpg" border="0"></a><BR>
          <a href="/prj1//ex12Servlet?action=exampleForm" class="wlcmlink">HELP FILE</a><BR>
    <a href="/prj1//ex12Servlet?action=exampleForm" class="wlcmlink">CODE FILE</a><BR>
</TD>
```

Comment: Post you HTML source code.

Comment: Sorry, here is my html code

<TD align="left" width="185px" NOWRAP valign="top">
 <a class="wlcmhding"><IMG  SRC="../../images/image1.jpg" border="0"></a><BR>
 <a href="/prj1//ex12Servlet?action=exampleForm" class="wlcmlink">HELP FILE</a><BR>
 <a href="/prj1//ex12Servlet?action=exampleForm" class="wlcmlink">CODE FILE</a><BR>
</TD> 
  ------
 </TD>

Comment: Divya please make your question more clear. Are you trying to retrieve the `HelpFile` text from `href` tag? Am i right?

Comment: yes i am trying to retrive HelpFile and Code File

Comment: Manigandan thank u for your reply, the problem for me over here is that team did not assign any id for it

Comment: can you please tell me if there is any method where we can try using tags

Comment: I hope my answer helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code:**

```java
// Assume driver in initialized  properly
String strText = driver.findElement(By.id("Locator id")).getText();
// Print the text of the Web Element
System.out.println(strText);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer that will return the WebElement inside the  tag that has the same String query (Help File). Hopefully this will help you, not sure i understood the question though.

It strikes me as you want to manipulate the WebElement according the text that is present within, so this method will most likely work for you.

```java
public WebElement getMessage(final WebDriver driver, final String query) {
    List<WebElement> wlcmLinks = driver.findElements(By.className("wlcmlink"));
    WebElement finalLink = null;
    Iterator<WebElement> itr = wlcmLinks.iterator();

    while(itr.hasNext() && (finalLink == null)) {
        WebElement link = itr.next();
        if (link.getText().equals(query)) {
           finalLink = link;
        }
    }

    if (finalLink == null) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("No <a /> with that String");
    }

    return finalLink;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. It might work..

String helpFile =                           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[1]//a[1]//*@class='wlcmlink']")).getText();

String codeFile = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[1]//a[2]//*@class='wlcmlink']")).getText();

Comment: Change td[] number where your text present.